# Trying to use the overflow-X: "hidden"; but it doesn't working in the mobile screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

**when I try to minimize the width the `overflow-x: hidden` works but when I try to display it in small screens with google feature it override the overflow x hidden and I dont know why?!**

```css
@media (max-width:768px) {
    body{
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .list{
        position: absolute;
        top: 8vh;
        right: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 92vh;
        color: #eee;
        transform: translate(100%);
        background-color: rgb(110, 164, 172);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .list li{opacity: 0;}
    .burgger{display: block;}
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burgger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

The browsers on mobile devices ignore the overflow-x:hidden within the body and html tag if `<meta name="viewport">` tag is present. I suggest you to try:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x:hidden 
}
```

(not only body)

Or to create a site wrapper div inside the `<body>` and applying the `overflow-x:hidden` and `position: relative` to that wrapper instead of the `<body>` or/and `<html>`.

Best Regards, ykostov

Comment: when I try this the menu stops appearing even when I click the button.

Comment: Did you try to isolate with div wrapper only the elements you want to have the overflow:hidden?

Comment: yes and also the same issue (the menu stops appearing even when I click the button)